# Can I use Visual Assist X on more than one machine?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-assist, visual-assist-x

A copy of the Visual Studio plug-in [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/default.asp) costs US$250, or US$50 for an academic licence.

However, I code as much on my laptop as I do on my desktop, so I'm guessing I have to buy 2 licenses?

Comment: I usually don't like lack of research effort in questions but, in this case -- a self-answered question -- the research effort _is_ the answer. So just enjoy it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always thought that per-user rather than per-machine licences were far more fair because, just in the same way multi-car insurance policies work, you're likely to be *splitting* your time between the two installations rather than using them concurrently.

However, this is not as clearly true in the case of software as it is in driving a car. It's also intractible to enforce per-user licences, whereas per-machine licencing is largely feasible.

Regardless, [the *Whole Tomato* purchasing FAQ](http://www.wholetomato.com/purchase/faq.asp) explains that in the case of *Visual Assist X*, the licensing *is* per-user:

> **I want to use Visual Assist X on my desktop and my laptop. Do I need two licenses?**
>   No. Visual Assist X is licensed per user; you are welcome to use our software on more than one machine under your exclusive control using a single license.

Comment: That's good to know, because what I might have suggested probably would have been against the terms and conditions of StackOverflow... ;-)

Comment: @paddy: And of _Whole Tomato_!

Comment: I'd add that Visual Studio itself is also licensed per user.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what the FAQ says, if your laptop and desktop are on the same network, the [Visual Assist license check](http://support.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W125) prevents you from using it on both machines at the same time.  As I think this is the direct opposite of what their FAQ says, I have opened a support incident and will report any outcome here.

EDIT:  Tech support gave me a workaround.

Comment: I agree. They seem to be trying to prevent multiple people within an organisation sharing a licence but, in doing so, they break the meaning of "per-user licence" with phrases like _"Multiple instances of an IDE on one PC count as one user during a license check."_ Per-user should not mean per-machine.